# Can ElasticSearch tell me where it found the results of a query string?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does anyone try to know where elastic get its results?

For example : 
my type :
{
name1 : foo,
name2 : bar
}

If I search "foo" I would like to know that elastic find it in the filed 'name1'.

I can do that within the results but if elastic can work for me, that would be great.

T cannot manage to find anything relevant.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you construct your own query and would like to which subqueries are responsible for the results, you can use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html).

If you want to where in the field Elasticsearch found the match, look into [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html).

With both you will need to beyond the simple query string search you might be using.  I apologize if I misunderstood your request.

Comment: Thank you I'm pretty sure the highlighting is what i was looking for.

But I don't really understand the "With both you will need to beyond the simple query string search you might be using." part.

Comment: I meant that you would need to submit the query as a payload to your POST request to the search endpoint constructed using the query language instead of some query text in the query string which I think the same endpoint accepts.